# Can a MenuStrip control have its LayoutStyle set to StackWithOverflow?

Tags: .net, winforms, menustrip

I create a simple form with a MenuStrip. The MenuStrip's `LayoutStyle` is set to `HorizontalStackWithOverflow` (the default).

According to the [MSDN reference on MenuStrip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menustrip_members%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), its [LayoutStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.layoutstyle%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) property is inherited from ToolStrip. One of the possible values for the LayoutStyle is `HorizontalStackWithOverflow` which is also the default setting. This setting should provide items with its `Overflow` property set to AsNeeded are moved to an overflow button.

When I run the application and resize the form so the menu won't fit completely, this doesn't happen. I've set my ToolStripMenuItems Overflow property to AsNeeded, but when I resize the form, the menu items on the right just disappear.

Is the documentation wrong and can you only get an overflowbutton on a ToolStrip and not on a MenuStrip? Or is there something else I have to do in order to get things working? Or am I just misreading the documentation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just had the same problem, and found a way to get it working.

On the MenuStrip you need to set:

```
myMenuStrip.CanOverflow = True
```

*The default is false.*

Then for each MenuItem you need to set:

```
myToolStripMenuItem.Overflow = ToolStripItemOverflow.AsNeeded
```

or

```
myToolStripMenuItem.Overflow = ToolStripItemOverflow.Always
```

*The default is ToolStripItemOverflow.Never*

References:

[MenuStrip.CanOverflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menustrip.canoverflow.aspx)

[ToolStripMenuItem.Overflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem.overflow.aspx)

Comment: It works: `myMenuStrip.CanOverflow = True` is really the key. @comecme: consider marking as accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

The ToolStrip classes have plenty of hairs like this.  I think the appropriate selection here is LayoutStyle = Flow to get the menu items wrapped.  This is the way the built-in Windows menus work.

You do however have to take care of the layout problem this causes.  Put a Panel on the form with Dock = Fill so that all controls automatically move down when the menu strip needs more space.

Comment: With LayoutStyle=Flow at least the menu items don't disappear anymore. But you you're saying is it isn't possible to use an OverflowButton on a MenuStrip? So either the documentation is wrong or it is a bug?

Comment: Not sure it matters, it just doesn't work.  I'm 95% sure you can't make it work.  You could file a feedback report at connect.microsoft.com.  They have however been closing Winforms bug reports for the past couple of years with "won't fix".  You have a good workaround, I recommend you use it.