# .NET, arrows on the right side in MenuStrip

Tags: .net, toolstrip, menustrip

When not all items fit in a ToolStrip, there are arrows on the right side.
Is there the same possibility for MenuStrip?

'LayoutStyle = Flow' is not so good, cause then the menu takes more lines and the user has less space to work.

[image: Arrows]

Comment: [`CanOverflow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menustrip.canoverflow(v=vs.110).aspx)?  Note the remarks about also setting a property on items within it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comment, I found the answer:

[Can a MenuStrip control have its LayoutStyle set to StackWithOverflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726551/can-a-menustrip-control-have-its-layoutstyle-set-to-stackwithoverflow)

```
    Me.MenuStrip1.CanOverflow = True
    Me.FischersToolStripMenuItem.Overflow = ToolStripItemOverflow.AsNeeded
```